# Where to get the default shortcuts for all the commands in vimrc file? (like ts for tabstop)

Tags: vim, editor, configuration-files, text-editor, vi

I want to make my vimrc file crisp. So I want to know where I can get all the abbreviatoins for all the commands like ts for tabstop, sw for shiftwidth, etc?

Comment: Don't do that. It will make your `vimrc` unreadable for no reason (no meaningful weight loss, no performance boost).

Comment: I will write the explanation in comments. I need it because I will carry the printout of the vimrc file in programming contests, where I will be required to type my vimrc again.

Comment: @spharish : You can find them in quickref.txt :)

Comment: Thank you @SibiCoder , i am updating it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be found by searching the command name here,

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickref.html

Or, you can search it in vim itself with help command.

```
 :help quickref
```